# android can't change font in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-fonts

I'm trying to change the font of my a webview element. I created a web page and placed the .ttf file besides it. I opened the page and it looked fine. Now I want to use a webview to display it. Since I'm using twitter bootstrap, I use  `loadUrl` method to load the page.

The page does load but the font is wrong. In my css style file I tried these (my html file is in my assets folder in 'www' directory and I put the font in that folder as well):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Far.TitrDF';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/www/Far_TitrDF.ttf');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Far.TitrDF';
    src: url('Far_TitrDF.ttf');
}
```

I also tried creating a 'fonts' directory in assets folder and putting my font there and trying these:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Far.TitrDF';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Far_TitrDF.ttf');
} 


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Far.TitrDF';
    src: url('../fonts/Far_TitrDF.ttf');
}
```

But no success. It's funny that everything else, like styles, is displayed fine. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

its bad idea for change web view font, if your data is only text prefer way is use TextView and SetTypeface method...

but still you can use custom font for web view by mix html and css and font command in css, but font must be web font not any font and in font url there is no sub folder

Comment: Some times we you need show external info of uri or html type, for this is necessary use a webview. In my case i need show a html info this have a default style but the webview can't recognize the font.

Answer (score 0):

```
String data="<html><head><meta      http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;\" charset=\"UTF-8\"><style>"+
        "@font-face {"+
          "font-family: \"MyFont\";"+
          "src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/normal.otf');"+
          "font-weight:bold !important;"+
        "}"+
        "@font-face {"+
          "font-family: \"MyFontBold\";"+
          "src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/bold.otf');"+
          "font-weight:bold !important;"+
        "}"+
        "@font-face {"+
          "font-family: \"MyFontItalic\";"+
          "src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Italic.otf');"+
          "font-weight:bold !important;"+
        "}"+
        "@font-face {"+
          "font-family: \"BoldItalic\";"+
          "src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/BoldItalic.otf');"+
          "font-weight:bold !important;"+
        "}"+
        "strong { font-family:\"MyFontBold\"; }"+
        "em {font-family :\"MyFontItalic\";}"+
        "body { font-family:\"MyFont\"; }"+
        "body strong em {font-family:\"BoldItalic\";}"+ 
        "body em  strong{font-family:\"BoldItalic\";}"+
        "</style>"+
        "</head>"+
        "<body>"+your description String+ "</body></html>";


        web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html",
                "UTF-8", "null");
```